# compute distance between descriptors extracted with dog

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm trying to match the patches I got using dog blob detection. I've been through Jan Solem book about computer vision with python and I have found :

```
def match(desc1,desc2,threshold=0.5):

    n = len(desc1[0])

    d = -ones((len(desc1),len(desc2)))
    for i in range(len(desc1)):
        for j in range(len(desc2)):
            d1 = (desc1[i] - mean(desc1[i])) / std(desc1[i])
            d2 = (desc2[j] - mean(desc2[j])) / std(desc2[j])
            ncc_value = sum(d1 * d2) / (n-1)
            if ncc_value > threshold:
                d[i,j] = ncc_value
    ndx = argsort(-d)
    matchscores = ndx[:,0]
    return matchscores
```

which is useful if you use harris corner detection, but with my features raise a ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (81,) (0,).

How could I implement an effective code for a different blob detector which does the same things that this does (compute distances using negative cross correlation)?

Comment: your code format might be wrong, can I update it ?

Comment: yes it is sorry, I've just noticed that the indentetion is uncorrect. I'll fix it. But notice that it's not working even with the correct indentation if I use the blobs from dog blob detection.

Comment: Please give at least some informations: 1) What line rise `ValueError`? What do `desc1` and `desc2` been? (signature and shape if they are `numpy.array`)

Comment: It seems that you cannot write `sum(d1 * d2) / (n-1)`.. and maybe what you cannot do is `d1 * d2`: `d1` is a one dimensional array of 81 and `d2` is a zero len array (???)

Comment: You must decide what you want to do: if `len(desc1)!=len(desc2)` have not too much sense to compute the cross correlation like this but you must chose a window of `desc1` (for instance if it is the bigger one) and compute it on the window: you can move the windowd to look for the best cross correlation.

Comment: yep the error is: line 45, in match ncc_value = sum(d1 * d2) / (n-1. I'm using as descriptor the patches obtained from the dog blob detection so descriptors 1 and descriptors 2 are patches from image 1 and image 2. The shape of my descriptors are (342,)
(358,), respectively.

Comment: @theggg What is `desc1[0]` it seams a scalar when you get it for `n` and a vector when you compute `d1` for `i==0`

Comment: @theggg Maybe is better that you split `sum(d1 * d2) / (n-1)` in two rows and print the shape of the element (and the indexes). I'm not so sure the problem is `d1 * d2`, it could be the division too.

Comment: if I remove the division I get the same error, so I guess it depends on the sum?

Comment: @theggg pay attention to desc2: desc2[j] seams to be a scalar against vector desc1[i]

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for ``skimage.feature.match_template``

Comment: @Stefan I've tried to use that, but I'm not sure on what do I have to use as a template (which is the second parameter if I remember correctly). My second image? The patches? Or do I have to extract a template ex novo?

Comment: `match_template` calculates the normalized cross-correlation, so you can provide your two patches as input and use the resulting value.